# Questions regarding solidity syntax

Tags: solidity

I come from an OOP background but solidity is new to me. Overall I'm not having big issues understanding the language but I do have some questions, specifically with parentheses in some cases. What I know:
Sometimes it serves as type casting, for example:

```
int256 = price;
uint256(price); // converts int256 into uint256

msg.sender // address
payable(msg.sender) // payable address
```

What confuses me the most:

```
contract StorageFactory is SimpleStorage {

    SimpleStorage[] public simpleStorageArray;

    function createSimpleStorageContract() public {
        SimpleStorage simpleStorage = new SimpleStorage();
        simpleStorageArray.push(simpleStorage);
    }

    function sfStore(uint256 _storageIndex, uint256 _storageNumber) public {

        // what does this next line do? I'm assuming it returns the contract so I can
        // interact with it
        SimpleStorage(address(simpleStorageArray[_storageIndex])).store(_storageNumber);
    }
}
```

why do I have to instantiate a new empty array like this?
`new address[](0);`

I'm not mentioning obvius cases like function parameters( function(parameterA, parameterB) ),
or function initializations( something(); ). It's like the syntax in some cases confuses me.
Will I get used to it eventually or there's some stuff I have to learn before moving on?
I hope I made myself clear, I know it's kind of an ambiguous question but I will really appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SimpleStorage(address(simpleStorageArray[_storageIndex])).store(_storageNumber);
```

Let’s expand it onto multiple lines:

```
SimpleStorage contract = simpleStorageArray[_storageIndex];
address contractAddress = address(contract);
SimpleStorage contractAgain = SimpleStorage(conractAddress);
contract.store(_storageNumber);
```

So the first two lines are just making a round-trip. You are upcasting the the `SimpleStorage` reference to a raw `address`, and then you are downcasting the raw `address` as a `SimpleStorage` reference again. You could have simply done:

```
SimpleStorage contract = simpleStorageArray[_storageIndex];
contract.store(_storageNumber);
```

---

Regarding parentheses in the context of contracts, addresses, etc.…

If we make up an address right now e.g. `0x0123456789012345678901234567890123456789`, and “dress” it as a `SimpleStorage`, Solidity isn’t going to stop us. Consider:

```
SimpleStorage contract = SimpleStorage(0x0123456789012345678901234567890123456789);
contract.store(999);
```

What the first line is saying is “whatever there is at `0x0123456789012345678901234567890123456789`, we are going to “look at it” as a  `SimpleStorage`”… but the first line doesn’t actually execute anything, it’s just a declaration, so it’s never going to fail, regardless of what is sitting behind that address. But when at runtime on the second line you will try and call `store(uint256)` on it, if at `0x0123456789012345678901234567890123456789` there actually *isn’t* a contract that has a `store(uint256)` function, the transaction will revert.

---

What you are asking about `new address[](0)` is something unrelated. This syntax is used to instantiate a `memory` array of item-type `address`. It is saying “instantiate in (volatile) memory an address-array of size 0.” Once a transaction is over, any data written to volatile-memory during the transaction disappears.